# Valgrind - Errores

Tags: c

```
char* file_read_line(const char* path){
    FILE *fp;
    char buffer[32];
    fp = fopen(path, "r");
    fread(buffer, 1, sizeof(buffer), fp);
    char *full_line = (char*) malloc(32);
    memcpy(full_line, buffer, strlen(buffer)+1);
    int n = 2;
    while (strchr(full_line, '\n') == NULL){
        memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));
        full_line = realloc(full_line, n*32);
        fread(buffer, 1, sizeof(buffer), fp);
        memcpy(&full_line[(n-1)*32], buffer, sizeof(buffer));
        n++;
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return full_line;
}

char* file_clean_line(char *file_line){
    int i = 0;
    char *clean_line = (char *) malloc(1);
    while (file_line[i] != '\n'){
        clean_line = realloc(clean_line, sizeof(char)*(i+1));
        clean_line[i] = file_line[i];
        i++;
    }
    free(file_line);
    return clean_line;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]){
    char *read_line = file_read_line(argv[1]);
    char *clean_line = file_clean_line(read_line);
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(clean_line); i++){
        printf("%c",clean_line[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Hola! Soy nuevo en el uso de memoria dinámica, y me lo están exigiendo para un TP de la facultad. Necesito leer un archivo en bloques de 32 bytes, e ir obteniendo las líneas del mismo. Este archivo puede contener varias líneas. El código hace lo que necesito correctamente, pero al correrlo con Valgrind, me arroja una serie de errores que no se interpretar/corregir. Alguien me podría ayudar? Gracias!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a la comunidad. Te invito a hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer [¿cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea bien recibida por parte de la comunidad. Además, para poder reproducir tu problema y encontrar una solución fácilmente nos sería de gran ayuda un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). ¿Podrías copiar y pegar la salida de Valgrind en vez de poner una captura de pantalla? Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

> Necesito leer un archivo en bloques de 32 bytes

```
char buffer[32];
fp = fopen(path, "r");
fread(buffer, 1, sizeof(buffer), fp);
char *full_line = (char*) malloc(32);
memcpy(full_line, buffer, strlen(buffer)+1);
```

Pues si son bloques de 32 bytes ya empezamos mal. En C las cadenas finalizan **SIEMPRE** con el caracter nulo, luego para almacenar 32 caracteres necesitamos un variable con capacidad para 33 elementos:

```
char buffer[33];
char *full_line = (char*) malloc(33);
```

Por otro lado, si estás copiando cadenas, es preferible usar `strcpy` a `memcpy`:

```
memcpy(full_line, buffer, strlen(buffer)+1);

strcpy(full_line, buffer);
```

Otra cosa más: Esta línea es peligrosa:

```
clean_line = realloc(clean_line, sizeof(char)*(i+1));
```

Si por algún casual te quedas sin memoria, `realloc` fallará y te devolverá un puntero nulo... pero la dirección apuntada por `clean_file` seguiría siendo válida!!!

Como reemplazas el valor sin verificar nada... perderás el puntero irremediablemente:

```
void* ptr = realloc(...);
if( ptr == NULL )
{
  // Error de memoria
  // ...
}
clean_line = ptr;
```

Y para terminar, no le encuentro sentido a esta línea:

```
memcpy(&full_line[(n-1)*32], buffer, sizeof(buffer));
```

Teniendo en cuenta que `full_line` tendrá capacidad para 33 elementos... en cuanto `n` tenga un valor superior a 2 escribirás fuera de los límites del array.